# Linear Independence of n+2 points in projective space

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Suppose $P_0,\dots P_{n+1}$ are $n+2$ points in projective space, such that no $n+1$ lie on a hyperplane. Does there exist a linear automorphism $f$ with the property that

$f(P_0)=(1:0:\dots:0)$

$f(P_1)=(0:1:0:\dots:0)$

$f(P_{n+1})=(1:1:\dots:1)$?

Clearly, linear algebra should/can be used, at least to get an idea of how to construct such an automorphism. However, I am having trouble seeing how to do such a thing for $n+2$ arbitrary points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you're in $\Bbb P^n$? ... Anyhow, the answer is yes.

**HINT**: The points correspond (up to choices of scalars) to vectors in $\Bbb K^{n+1}$, whatever your field $\Bbb K$ is, the first $n+1$ of which are linearly independent. So define a linear map $T\colon\Bbb K^{n+1}\to\Bbb K^{n+1}$ by sending them them to the standard basis vectors. Now show that you can choose the scalars to get $T$ to send the last vector to $(1,1,\dots,1)$.